# Can you use Powershell Remotely to reset AD passwords for Server 2008

Tags: windows-server-2008, active-directory, powershell

Young intern here with a powershell project. My goal is to use a domain computer with administrative [domain] rights to reset user passwords in AD from our server.

In order to do so, I have installed Vmware and, to my extent, setup a VM Server 2008 (not r2) and a domained VM Win 7 cpu. I'm not sure if everything is configured correctly, but my Win7 cpu already has the RSAT tool installed, set up for remoting, and it connected to the domain properly.

I can't find any commands for resetting the password in powershell (except for 2008 r2). Is this something I can import? Updating to r2, unfortunately, is not an option. **Is it even possible to use powershell to remotely reset passwords?** I don't necessarily need to know how, just if it's possible.

lastly, sry if these are noob questions, this was my first server setup and I'm a bit lost :/

thanks guys!

Comment: I thought that could only be used for 2008 r2? If not, if i'm in powershell on a domained computer w/domain admin rights, after I import the user in PS I can use that line to change the password?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Install the [Active Directory Management Gateway Service](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=2852), it will let the Microsoft Active Directory Powershell modules work with 2003/2008 Domains.

Then use the Powershell Active Directory module and the [`Set-ADAccount`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee617261.aspx) cmdlet to perform resets.

Comment: thanks jscott! able to add, delete, + modify my AD accounts on my domained win7 cpu. Thanks for the help! –

Comment: @Bob Cool, glad I was able to help. Also of note: You can use [delegation of permissions](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=21678) in AD so you don't need to do everything as a Domain Admin. And... because you're new to SE: [How does accepting an answer work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Answer (score 1):

Before R2, pretty much everyone were using the free [Active Directory CmdLets from Quest](http://www.quest.com/powershell/activeroles-server.aspx), which are still available. IMHO, they're still easier to work with than Microsoft's, and don't require a 2008R2-level DC.

Answer (score 0):

I found a powershell script that might be helpful:

https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Reset-password-for-all-412fbc72

Comment: What does it do?